# A good example on how to use UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit with MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I'm trying to figure out how to use UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit.

I've got following form:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="10" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Window, Mode=OneWay}">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Proxy address:" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding User.PageAddress, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" Margin="28,0,0,0"/>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel Margin="0,5,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="User name:" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding User.UserName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" Margin="46,0,0,0"/>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel Margin="0,5,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="User password:" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding  User.Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" Margin="26,0,0,0"/>
    </DockPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,0,0">
        <Button Content="Ok" IsDefault="True" Width="70" Margin="0,0,15,0" Click="Ok_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Cancel" IsCancel="True" Width="70"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

what method should I call to update `User` property?

I don't want to address the elements by x:Name to invoke the binding. If I have to address the elements by x:Name, I as well can go without binding altogether, as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 11):

You need to call [BindingExpression.UpdateSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatesource.aspx) in the code behind to manually update the binding.  Explicit binding isn't really compatible with MVVM since you need to directly reference the view objects to perform the manually update.

```
// itemNameTextBox is an instance of a TextBox
BindingExpression be = itemNameTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
be.UpdateSource();
```

Comment: A bit late, but if you just handle a button click in code-behind, things are still happening and referencing each other only in the View, and the ViewModel will only receive update notifications from the bindings.