# How to edit properties of a ViewModel object but only apply changes when clicking a button in the View

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, submit

My screen has a list of objects of type `Person`, and a form that displays the person properties (name, address, weight, etc.) via databinding.

I want to be able to:

1. Click in a button "Edit properties", and start modifying the person's properties (I can already do that using `Command`s in the ViewModel);
2. If I click "Cancel", the edited info "rollback" to the original unmodified values of that person;
3. If I click "Save changes", JUST THEN the person's name changes in the person list.

My problem right now is that, as I am editing the forms, the original properties are updated, so to say, in realtime, and if I decide to cancel, I have not the original values to "go back".

I considered to `Clone` the selected person, but that seemed to be odd. I think a better approach would be to change only the text properties of the field, and update back only when clicking to submit changes, but I don't know how to do it, specially how to preserve databinding consistency.

Comment: What `UIElement`s are you using to display & edit the properties?

Comment: @Omribitan Mostly TextBoxes, but also one DatePicker and one ComboBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind, use [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx)`=`[`Explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx). That will tell XAML not to update the source binding until you tell it to.  Then, when your Save button is clicked, you can call [`UpdateSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatesource.aspx) on the binding to push the contents of your controls back to the `Person` object, something like:

```
var nameBinding = nameTextBox.GetBindingExpression( TextBox.TextProperty );
nameBinding.UpdateSource();
```

To cancel, use [`UpdateTarget`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatetarget%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead, which will push the data in the `Person` object back to your control.

Comment: That sounds great, EXCEPT that the ViewModel would have to reference the View. Anyway, I'll think about your suggested strategy, it agrees with what I was vaguely trying to do.

Comment: Here is something to consider, although it looks like it doesn't use commands but rather handling the "click" event right in the codebehind (so everything would happen in the view). http://stackoverflow.com/a/10394257/401828

Comment: Well, I guess the code you show is part of the CodeBehind file, so This is the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: There's a lot of talk about model-view separation and whatnot... I say take the simple solution that will allow your code to work and move on to the next problem instead of jumping through all kind of hoops to ensure M/V separation.  Besides, as you say, this is all in the view, and you're not touching the Person object so there is still separation.  Anyway, thanks for the accept!

Comment: I tend to disagree that you should "move on" too soon. I quote Josh Smith on something that I have already seen some times, even being in the business for just a couple of years: "There are popular design patterns that can help to tame this unwieldy beast, but properly separating and addressing the multitude of concerns can be difficult. The more complicated the patterns are, the more likely that shortcuts will be used later on which undermine all previous efforts to do things the right way."

Answer (score 2):

You can try it with this Undo/Redo approch

http://blog.notifychanged.com/2009/01/30/using-the-viewmodel-pattern-to-provide-undo-redo-in-wpf/

Or

You could have a a Current and Previous property created in View model to which is going to hold the edited values and the other will have original value. The required action of rollback can be performed be reassigning the values

Answer (score 0):

There are also open-source projects available to help with this, including http://undo.codeplex.com/