# Refresh DataBinding From View To ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

i have a problem with databinding in my WPF project. I´m using the MVVM pattern and i like to reload the textvalue of a textbox to my viewmodel.

I´m searching for an event, like INotifyPropertyChanged, but the bindingdirection should be from the view to the viewmodel.

And i would trigger this binding update from the viewmodel.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: wpf supports 2-way binding

Comment: I should say that i want trigger this binding update from the viewmodel. 
Is this possible?

Comment: use updateSourceTrigger=OnPropertyChanged and Binding Mode = TwoWays to acheive your goal

Answer (score 3):

If i understand your question correctly, you mean this:

> The changes in the View (TextBox) will not update the ViewModel (String Property) Automatically.
>
> Only by calling **Explicit** the `UpdateSource()`, then the View will update your ViewModel.
>
> So how do you call explicit the `UpdateSource()` from the ViewModel?

I don't know if there is a way to do this, because in MVVM the VM doesn't know about the View.

You can set the `UpdateSourceTrigger = Explicit`, and then call `UpdateSource()` from the code behind, [but isn't really compatible with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392698/a-good-example-on-how-to-use-updatesourcetrigger-explicit-with-mvvm).

You can set the `UpdateSourceTrigger = OneWay`, and use a "Save button" with your `TextBox.Text` as Button.CommandParameter. [Example](http://www.shujaat.net/2011/01/updatesourcetrigger-explicit-for-mvvm.html)

But the real question is: why do you not want to update the source Automatically?

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like a Refresh Button?

I think than you have do implement an `ICommand` telling your ViewModel, that the View wants to be refreshed.

Or do you just want to Trigger every user edit of your Textblock?Then you have to extend your Binding by `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: i will that my viewmodel is telling my view, that the viewmodel will be refreshed from the view.

Answer (score 0):

**Update ViewModel from View**
UpdateSourceTrigger property of your binding tells wpf engine when to update viewmodel.
If you want viewmodel to be updated on every change then set it to "PropertyChanged".

Other values that it supports can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Mode decides the flow.
[this](http://geekswithblogs.net/mamta_m/archive/2010/07/04/wpf-binding-mode.aspx) link would give more information on different modes

**Update View From ViewModel**

View is updated whenever PropertyChanged(from 
INotifyPropertyChanged  interface) is fired.
Dependency Property is another option.